# Elastic Search - search the data ignoring periods or

Tags: elasticsearch

The elastic search index has the data having CPFs.

```
{
  "name": "A",
  "cpf": "718.881.683-23",
}

{
  "name": "B",
  "cpf": "404.833.187-60",
}
```

I want to search the data by field cpf as following:

```
query: 718
output: doc with name "A"
```

```
query: 718.881.683-23
output: doc with name "A"
```

The above is working.

But the following is not working.

```
query: 71888168323
output: doc with name "A"
```

Here I want to search the doc by field CPF data but without period and hyphen also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom analyzer that will remove all characters that are not digits and only index the digits.

The analyzer looks like this:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "number_only": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "\\D"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "cpf_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "number_only"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "cpf": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "cpf_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can index your documents as usual:

```
POST test/_doc
{
  "name": "A",
  "cpf": "718.881.683-23"
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "name": "B",
  "cpf": "404.833.187-60"
}
```

Searching for a prefix like `718` can be done like this:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "cpf": "718"
    }
  }
}
```

Searching for the exact value with non-digit characters can be done like this:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "cpf": "718.881.683-23"
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, you can also search with numbers only:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "cpf": "71888168323"
    }
  }
}
```

With the given analyzer, all the above queries will return the document you expect.

If you cannot recreate your index for whatever reason, you can create a sub-field with the right analyzer and update your data in place:

```
PUT test/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "cpf": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "numeric": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "cpf_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then simply run the following command which will reindex all the data in place and populate the `cpf.numeric` field:

```
POST test/_update_by_query
```

All your searches will then need to be done on the `cpf.numeric` field instead of `cpf` directly.

Comment: can I update the mapping of the field as the data is already saved in index?

Comment: will the keyword tokenizer actually work?

Comment: I've tested the above on a real cluster and it behaves as described. If you can't recreate your index, one way is to create a sub-field `cpf.numeric` with the above analyzer. I've updated my answer to show you how

Comment: I'm getting the exception `resource_already_exists_exception`

Comment: I don't think you're doing it right, please update your question with the steps you're trying

Comment: i'm just doing the put request to update the settings.

Comment: Please share the full error otherwise it won't be easy

Comment: `{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
                "reason": "index [firebase_clients/i4YgcpXVTFGZIS-x-8OyVQ] already exists",
                "index": "firebase_clients",
                "index_uuid": "i4YgcpXVTFGZIS-x-8OyVQ"
            }
        ],
        "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason": "index [firebase_clients/i4YgcpXVTFGZIS-x-8OyVQ] already exists",
        "index": "firebase_clients",
        "index_uuid": "i4YgcpXVTFGZIS-x-8OyVQ"
    },
    "status": 400
}`

Comment: I think you're missing `/_mapping` in the URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242119/discussion-between-deepak-goyal-and-val).

Comment: Case solved in the chat

Answer (score 1):

`718.881.683-23` is tokenized to `718 881 683 23` by the standard analyzer. So by default, you will find the document A with `718`, `718 881`, `718 and 23`, but not with `7188` as there is no such token in the field. Probably you want to [specify a different analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/specify-analyzer.html), for example using the [edge n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html).

You can create a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) specifying a filter - for example, a [pattern replace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) like the following (strips everything that is not a digit)

```
"my_char_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[^\d]",
          "replacement": ""
}
```

and a edge n-gram

```
  "my_tokenizer": {
           "type": "edge_ngram",
           "min_gram": 1,
           "max_gram": 11,
           "token_chars": [
             "digit"
           ]
   }
```

Comment: how to add an analyzer that will remove the periods or hyphens i.e. non digits from the field data.